# Find lowest elevation point for each of 5,000 parcels

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, esri, arcmap

I have two data layers: a LiDAR elevation data layer for a 10 square mile area and a second layer with polygons for each parcel in that area. Is there a way to use GIS to loop through each parcel and find the lowest elevation for that parcel?

Comment: This should not require programming if you have access to ArcMap. Try a Spatial Join.